# MockWebServer and Retrofit with Callback

Tags: android, retrofit, mockwebserver

I would like to simulate network communication by MockWebServer. Unfortulatelly retrofit callbacks are never invoking. My code:

```
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("{}"));
    server.play();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setConverter(new MyGsonConverter(new Gson()))
            .setEndpoint(server.getUrl("/").toString()).build();

    restAdapter.create(SearchService.class).getCount(StringUtils.EMPTY,
            new Callback<CountContainer>() {

                @Override
                public void success(CountContainer countContainer, Response response) {
                    System.out.println("success");
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            });

    server.shutdown();
```

When i use retrofit without callbacks it works.

Comment: Do you need to attach your callback *BEFORE* you do `server.play()` ?

Comment: When I change order, this throws exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot retrieve port before calling play()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By having a `Callback` you are telling Retrofit to invoke the request and call the callback asynchronously. This means that your test is exiting before anything happens.

There are two ways to get this to work:

- Use a lock at the end of the test and wait until one of the callback methods are invoked.
- Pass an instance of a synchronous `Executor` (one that just calls `.run()` immediately) to `setExecutors` on the `RestAdapter.Builder` so that the background invocations and callback invocations happen synchronously.

Comment: +1 thanks, supplying the synchronous `executors` works great. Wouldnt a lock block the main thread and therefore not allow the callbacks to be executed (on the main thread) and therefore the lock never released? By 'lock' im thinking of something like a `CountDownLatch`

Comment: This does not work with retrofit 2. How do I make it to work in Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 4):

For retrofit 2 see the answer here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1259 You can supply the synchronous executor to an OkHttpClient (via its dispatcher) and set this client to the Retrofit.Builder. You can also set the same executor to the callbackExecutor.

For example:

```
CurrentThreadExecutor currentThreadExecutor = new CurrentThreadExecutor();
okhttp3.Dispatcher dispatcher = new okhttp3.Dispatcher(currentThreadExecutor);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new 
OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(dispatcher).build();

new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(httpUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .callbackExecutor(currentThreadExecutor)
        .build();
```

Example of CurrentThreadExecutor implementation:
https://gist.github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/38d6b4b277d0a0cfb3af

Comment: This should be accepted. Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use Mockinizer with MockWebServer:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .mockinize(mocks) // <-- just add this line
        .build()
```

And the requests/responses that you want to mock you can define in the `mocks` value. In your case it would look something like:

```
package com.appham.mockinizer.demo

import com.appham.mockinizer.RequestFilter
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse

val mocks: Map<RequestFilter, MockResponse> = mapOf(

    RequestFilter("/") to MockResponse().apply {
        setResponseCode(200)
        setBody("""{}""")
    }

)
```

See https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer